# Clojure macro Instantiation Exception

Tags: java, macros, clojure, javafx-2

I have a macro which works in the repl, and it seems to work in my code outside the `let` and also inside the `let` as follows.  However it also breaks and I have no idea why.  The macro basically just takes the first arg as a function to call, and puts `into-array` before the last set of arguments, and it adds the class of the final non-collection argument as a parameter to into-array, if it is in the java class heirarchy.

```
(defmacro jvar [method & args]
  (let [lastargs (last args)
        evaled-lastargs (eval lastargs)]
    (if (coll? evaled-lastargs)
      (let [firstargs (butlast args)
            klass (eval (last firstargs))
            supset (map #(supers (class %)) evaled-lastargs)
            common (apply intersection #{klass} supset)]
        (if (seq common)
          `(~method ~@(butlast firstargs) (into-array ~(first common) ~lastargs))
          `(~method ~@firstargs (into-array ~lastargs))))
      (throw (Error. "Last argument must be defn.")))))
```

Usages:
In Repl:

```
jfxcircles.core>  (macroexpand '(jvar Group. Node [(Circle. 100)]))
(new Group (clojure.core/into-array javafx.scene.Node [(Circle. 100)]))
jfxcircles.core> (jvar Group. Node [(Circle. 100)])
#<Group Group@c26729e>
```

In `let`:

```
(let [root (Group.)
      scene (Scene. root 800 600) ;etc. this is for JavaFX
      ...
      circ (Circle. 100)
      inner-group1 (jvar Group. [(Circle. 100)])        ; works
      inner-group2 (jvar Group. [circ])                 ; Instantiation Exception
      inner-group3 (jvar Group. [(Rectangle. 100 100)]) ; works
      inner-group4 (jvar Group. [(Rectangle. (.getWidth scene) 100)]) ; Instantiation exception
)
```

So basically it won't compile under certain circumstances that should otherwise be the same, and I'm unable to do macroexpand because it won't compile.  Any ideas?

thanks

Comment: `eval` does not see lexical context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The macro expander gets applied at compilation time; there is no way for it to manipulate runtime values of the forms it receives as arguments, `eval` or not, except in the sense that some forms will always have the same values during compilation and at runtime (self-evaluating forms, some constructor calls etc.). It is because of this sort of lucky coincidence that the macro presented in the question text sometimes appears to work; there is, however, no way to make it work in general without making the information it tries to obtain with `eval` into an explicit set of arguments.

Comment: NB. A. Webb's comment on the question is also correct; its consequence here is that while `circ`'s value at the point of invocation of `jvar` can be determined statically, `eval` will make no attempt to do it (by design). Of course if `circ` were initialized with an expression like `(make-circle 100)`, there would not be even a theoretical possibility of determining its runtime value during compilation.

Comment: Thanks!  I think I was leaning towards this understanding, but now I have a better idea of what to look for.  I think this means the output code emitted by the macro can no longer be just a one-liner, but instead must compute some stuff at runtime.